# How to control width of an error bar mark?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How can I control the horizontal size of the error bar mark? I want to modify it to represent a bin size i.e. extend them until adjacent error bars "touch" each other.

I can control the `width` of the mark with `error bars/error mark options={rotate=90, line width=Xpt}`; but there is no `height` equivalent which would do what I want to do.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[only marks,
  error bars/.cd,
    y dir=both,
    y explicit,
    error bar style={line width=2pt},
    error mark options={
      rotate=90,
      mark size=8pt,
      line width=2pt
    }
]
coordinates {
(0,1) +- (0,0.35665)
(1,1.5) +- (0,-0.35048)
(2,0) +- (0,0.150255)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```